# GNURadio OOT Module: pmt_dict_keys: wrong_type : #<unknown>

Tags: gnuradio

I am running some tests for a GNU Radio OOT Module, and although the tests **pass**, i get the following message:

`thread[thread-per-block[1]: <block conv_enc(0)>]: pmt_dict_keys: wrong_type : #<unknown>` multiple times, where `conv_enc` is one of the blocks i have created.

What could cause this message?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> `pmt_dict_keys: wrong_type : #<unknown>`

Most probably you are passing a `pmt` message to your block that is not a [dictionary](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Polymorphic_Types_(PMTs)#Dictionaries) and as a result you get an exception thrown from eithr `dict_keys` or `dict_values` functions.

From [pmt.cc](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/v3.8.4.0/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/pmt.cc#L747-L761)

```
pmt_t dict_keys(pmt_t dict)
{
    if (!is_dict(dict))
        throw wrong_type("pmt_dict_keys", dict);

    return map(car, dict);
}

pmt_t dict_values(pmt_t dict)
{
    if (!is_dict(dict))
        throw wrong_type("pmt_dict_keys", dict);

    return map(cdr, dict);
}
```

From [pmt_io.cc](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/v3.8.4.0/gnuradio-runtime/lib/pmt/pmt_io.cc#L111-L115)

```cpp
    error:
        // FIXME
        // port << "#<" << obj << ">";
        port << "#<unknown>";
    }
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, in that it analyzes the situation, refers to reference material, shows exactly where the problem happens, hence even gives a bit of insight into how you chase down these things. Awesome!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The issue was solved just by cleaning some stuff from my cache, so maybe an old version of my block caused it, since I did not change anything more.